# Dynamic Controls for PhoneApplicationPage

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, wpf-controls

i want to show a detail page of a model. depending on the type of the model (defined as a string property) i want to display certain controls (image, text, media .. )

in pseudo code i image it would look like:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="TestApp.FullscreenArtifactPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
    xmlns:testapp="clr-namespace:TestApp"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
>
    <!-- if(model.type == TEXT) -->
     <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Name="MimeText" Text="{Binding Mime}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!-- else if(model.type == IMAGE) -->

    <StackPanel>
        <Image Name="Image" Source="{Binding PayloadUri}"/>
    </StackPanel>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

I know that I can use a [DataTemplateSelector](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/implementing-windows-phone-7-datatemplateselector-and-customdatatemplateselector) in ListBoxes, but since i don't have a ListBox here, there is no onChangeContent Method called.

Any Suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your even can discard `ContentControl` in your `XAML` and instead of `ControlTemplate` you need to use `DataTemplate`

```
    <testapp:FullscreenTypeSelector CurrentItem="{Binding YourItem}">
        <testapp:FullscreenTypeSelector.ImageTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Name="Image" Source="{Binding PayloadUri}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </testapp:FullscreenTypeSelector.ImageTemplate>
        <testapp:FullscreenTypeSelector.TextTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Name="MimeText" Text="{Binding Mime}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </testapp:FullscreenTypeSelector.ImageTemplate>
    </testapp:FullscreenTypeSelector>
```

And define your selector in this way

```
 public class FullscreenTypeSelector : ContentControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentItemProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentItem", typeof (object), typeof (FullscreenTypeSelector), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

        public object CurrentItem
        {
            get
            {
                return (object) GetValue(CurrentItemProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(CurrentItemProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public bool IsNote
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public DataTemplate ImageTemplate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public DataTemplate TextTemplate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            //your condition goes here
            if (CurrentItem != null)
            {
                ContentTemplate = TextTemplate;
            }
            else
            {
                ContentTemplate = ImageTemplate;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: thx - i created the content control, but how do i bind the ContentTemplate to DataTemplateSelector - in xaml or in c#?

Comment: i added a gist for better understanding of my code:  https://gist.github.com/magegu/0e0bd53fcef25ce6aa81

Comment: @magegu, I have updated my answer, pls check if it now works for you.

Comment: thanks again almost there. how do i have to set up the data context within the page class with `CurrentItem="{Binding myItem}"` ? the CurrentItem is always null for me. Its declared as a `public static Item myItem;` within the class.

Comment: You can declare a non static property in your code behind and initialize `DataContext` of your `Selector`with this property, for example in `OnNavigatedTo`: `YourSelectorName.DataContext = YourProperty`. Don't forget to remove `CurrentItem="{Binding YourItem}"` from your current XAML.

Comment: thanks - its working now. also important to set the Content in the selctor: `<testapp:FullscreenTypeSelector Name="Selector" Content="{Binding}">`